# escape double quotes javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to run a certain image format when viewed on iphone and some flash video when otherwise

```
var uagent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();

 if (uagent.search("iphone") > -1){

  document.write("<img src=http://www.demiads.com/images/bc-1300119669-722.gif />");    }
else{   

document.write("<object classid=clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000 
codebase=http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0 width=728 height=90 id=lang align=middle style=margin-left:3px;>   
 <param name=allowScriptAccess value=sameDomain />      
 <param name=allowFullScreen value=false />         
 <param name=movie value=http://koha.net//repository/reklamat/17_05_12_131575_koha.net_hej_reveal_675x88px.swf /> 
 <param name=quality value=high /> 
 <param name=bgcolor value=#ffffff /> 
 <param name=wmode value=transparent />     
<embed src=http://koha.net//repository/reklamat/17_05_12_131575_koha.net_hej_reveal_675x88px.swf 
quality=high WMODE=transparent bgcolor=#ffffff width=728 height=90 
name=ifm_al align=middle allowScriptAccess=sameDomain 
allowFullScreen=false type=application/x-shockwave-flash 
pluginspage=http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer /> 
</object>"); 

 }
```

It works fine when tested, but the ad system doesn't show it in the publishers website. I checked the source code of a website and I noticed that a \ is added whenever either " or ' found, thus making it non-functional! I have tried to minimize the use of " or ' , but this is a far as I could go. Is there any way to get around this?  thank you in advance.

Result

```
 if (uagent.search(\"iphone\") > -1){

 document.write(\"<img src=http://www.demiads.com/images/bc-1300119669-722.gif />\");    }
 else{   

   document.write(\"<object classid=clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000 
   codebase=http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0      width=728 height=90 id=lang align=middle style=margin-left:3px;>   
   <param name=allowScriptAccess value=sameDomain />      
   <param name=allowFullScreen value=false />         
   <param name=movie value=http://koha.net//repository/reklamat/17_05_12_131575_koha.net_hej_reveal_675x88px.swf /> 
   <param name=quality value=high /> 
   <param name=bgcolor value=#ffffff /> 
   <param name=wmode value=transparent />     
   <embed src=http://koha.net//repository/reklamat/17_05_12_131575_koha.net_hej_reveal_675x88px.swf 
   quality=high WMODE=transparent bgcolor=#ffffff width=728 height=90 
   name=ifm_al align=middle allowScriptAccess=sameDomain 
   allowFullScreen=false type=application/x-shockwave-flash 
   pluginspage=http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer /> 
   </object>\"); 

     }
```

Comment: so, where in your posted example are these quotes being escaped? I don't see any quotes anywhere.

Comment: @ShpatFerizi Please post the resulting HTML code...

Comment: You can see the problem in your own question above. Notice how most of your JavaScript code is highlighted with a red-ish color, which means that it's interpreted as a string. It seems that you're just not allowed to have string literals in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Why are those attributes lacking in `""`? You know you can use single quotes like:

```
document.write('<img src="bc-1300119669-722.gif" />');
```

Comment: as I mentioned, this ad system adds a \ when " or ' used, that's why i have tried to minimize the use of either " or '

Comment: @ShpatFerizi You're not allowed to have string literals in your JavaScript code?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas so are you suggesting that what I'm trying to do is impossible?

Comment: @ShpatFerizi What are you trying to do anyway? I assume that the service does not allow what you are trying to do.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer I'm trying to show a compatible ad format when viewed on iphone and some flash movie on the rest of the browsers