# re-write javascript so that it doesn't contain " anywhere?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [escape double quotes javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688513/escape-double-quotes-javascript)

pardon me if this is a stupid question, but is it possible to write the following javascript without actually using " anywhere in either  php, javascript or jquery?

```
 var uagent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();

 if (uagent.search("iphone") > -1){

 document.write("<img src=http://www.demiads.com/images/bc-1300119669-722.gif />");    }
 else{   

document.write("<object classid=clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000 
codebase=http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0    width=728 height=90 id=lang align=middle style=margin-left:3px;>   
<param name=allowScriptAccess value=sameDomain />      
<param name=allowFullScreen value=false />         
<param name=movie value=http://koha.net//repository/reklamat/17_05_12_131575_koha.net_hej_reveal_675x88px.swf /> 
<param name=quality value=high /> 
<param name=bgcolor value=#ffffff /> 
<param name=wmode value=transparent />     
<embed src=http://koha.net//repository/reklamat/17_05_12_131575_koha.net_hej_reveal_675x88px.swf 
quality=high WMODE=transparent bgcolor=#ffffff width=728 height=90 
name=ifm_al align=middle allowScriptAccess=sameDomain 
allowFullScreen=false type=application/x-shockwave-flash 
pluginspage=http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer /> 
 </object>"); 
}
```

Comment: You could replace it with `'`

Comment: It is possible, but why would you want to do that?

Comment: It might be easier for you to redirect to a different page to handle the iPhone - and I'd recommend avoiding `document.write`, as better ways of DOM manipulation have been around for a while now.

Comment: quotation marks used to create a string-variable value, they are necessary for differentiating strings from other language types.

Comment: @nhahtdh you can see from above that I'm trying to show a certain image when viewed on iphone and some flash movie on the rest of the browsers, but THE SYSTEM, does not will not allow me to do it in the above fashion, or any other format which contains ' or ".

Comment: don't repost your [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688513/escape-double-quotes-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to "embed" your JavaScript source inside another file, maybe you should try to escape all the '"' chars in it using the standard \" syntax. It is supported in many languages like PHP, C and JavaScript itself.

Please note that, since you are embedding the \" inside a string, the "\" char should be escaped by itself, so usually you write: \\"

Answer (score 0):

Some information on strings in javascript:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#String

Short answer is you could switch them from `"` to `'` but not sure why you would want to do that.